# Elasticsearch, mapping type string cannot contain enabled false why?

Tags: elasticsearch

The enabled :false mapping in Elastic-Search mapping for data-types String and nested gives an error can you tell me what would be the reason for this?

Comment: which version of elastic u are using?

Comment: Elastic version 2.1.1

Comment: please read my answer below and provide the error msg and exception trace which u are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the mapping of your schema. Please use `_mapping` api of elastic-search to get it. Below is the example how you can hit it.

http://localhost:9200/jaipur/_mapping In this example `jaipur` is the index name.

Also please tell me the ES version you are using.

Latest ES version supports `boolean` data type. refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The enabled setting, which can be applied only to the mapping type **and to object fields.**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/enabled.html

Comment: What do you mean by mapping type

Comment: It means for mapping

Comment: In essence, you can use enabled setting only for object field when defining mapping for your index